# C#, MySql Connection must be valid and open

Tags: c#, mysql

Вот дебильный быть может вопрос

Есть программа на c# есть запрос к mySql выполняется уже примерно так:

```
while (!(Connect.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open))
{
  Connect.Open();
}
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(sqlQuery, Connect);
return command.ExecuteReader();
```

Вот в чем вопрос

При запросе на получение 50 строк выдает ошибку(Понимаю что не правильно, но каждый запрос отдельной командой, просто вызывается в конструкторе класса, при заполнении массива)

```
Connection must be valid and open.
```

Ну вот и собственно вопрос что может быть не так.

Comment: хотя в другом классе (так же дочернем от того же родителя) и по сотне нормально заполняется конструктор используется родительский

Comment: Вы держите где-то открытый reader, который использует тот же connection

Comment: Это врят ли на самом деле: 1) на reader другая ошибка 2) для каждого обращения создается новый connection. И самое странное ошибка то есть то нет. тоесть не каждый раз появляется, а через один - два прохода(все проходы идентичны, всмысле я произвожу одни и теже действия)

Comment: Вам +1 за "врят ли".

Comment: Покажите минимальный пример для воспроизведения проблемы. Покп похоже,  что вы где-то как-то неправильно работаете с соединением. А цикл с Open похож какой-то хак.

Comment: Ребята всем спасибо за внимание! Я разобрался. Суть в чем Сборщик мусора не успевал Дестройнуть все соединения и поэтому у меня выскакивала ошибка Too many connections переписал методы взаимодействия с соединением полностью вроде работает

Comment: Скажите, а зачем Вы пытаетесь открыть соединение в цикле? Я правильно понял, что оно может быть открыто кем-то еще, то есть используется в несколькими клиентами? Это в корне неверно, обратите на это внимание, возможно, дело именно в этом. И еще момент: от !(Connect.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open) кровоточат глаза, лучше все же так: Connect.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open

Answer (score 0):

Ребята всем спасибо за внимание! Я разобрался. Суть в чем Сборщик мусора не успевал Дестройнуть все соединения и поэтому у меня выскакивала ошибка Too many connections переписал методы взаимодействия с соединением полностью вроде работает

Comment: Сборщик мусора и не должен заниматься закрытием соединений. MySqlConnection - IDisposable, его нужно или оборачивать в using, или руками Close / Dispose вызывать. А что, что при сборке мусора соединение закрывается - это защита на случай совсем уж неправильного использования.

Comment: Почитайте про пулы соединений в ADO.NET, детерминированное освобождение неуправляемых ресурсов (подключение -- как раз такой), интерфейс IDisposable и оператор using.  Выше сказали верно: тот факт, что в финализаторе вызывается Dispose (именно так GC "закрывает" соединения) -- эффект побочный, более того, поскольку вызывается финализатор (при правильно реализованном IDisposable его вызов чаще всего отменяется), то объект переживает одну сборку мусора, а удаляется только при втором проходе сборщика. Это не есть хорошо.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/using-objects